# Нужна запятая и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

> ***Студент ищет, где лучше***

Нужна запятая или нет? И почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Студент ищет, где (ему) лучше.**

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении.

Сравнить: Он ночевал где придётся (= в разных местах). Это цельное по смыслу выражение с подчинительным союзом, запятая не ставится.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

**Примеры:**

Я так считаю, что рыба ищет, **где глубже**, а человек ― **где лучше**. [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]

Рыба ищет, **где глубже**, а человек ― **где лучше…** в моду вошло подбирать корешки и камешки, ракушки и сучья, что-нибудь, кроме себя, напоминавшие. [Андрей Битов. Жизнь без нас (1997)]

Рыба ищет, **где глубже,** а человек ― **где лучше.** [Евгений Шкловский. Состояние невесомости (1990-1996)]

Я не одобряю твоего решения, но, как говорят, **человек ищет, где лучше**, и я желаю тебе успеха. [Борис Левин. Блуждающие огни (1995)]

Народная пословица чётко фиксирует: рыба **ищет где глубже**, а человек ― где лучше. [Гавриил Попов, Никита Аджубей. Пять выборов Никиты Хрущева (журнальный вариант) // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]

Ведь я та самая колбасная эмигрантка, **я искала, где лучше**, я не от тюрьмы и не от смерти бежала, я просто утекла мозгами. [Любовь Гурова. В промежутке — жутко (2002) // «Неприкосновенный запас», 2002.09.12]

Конечно, миролюбиво рассуждал я, человек ищет, **где лучше**. [Алла Боссарт. Повести Зайцева // «Дружба народов», 1998]

**Выводы:**

1. **Многие классики ставили запятую** в пословице.
2. **Обобщенность** высказывания  в пословице может определить отсутствие запятой (ищет где лучше ― ищет лучшее место), однако в **конкретных** случаях (без сравнения) запятая ставится.
3. Но скорее всего  на постановку знаков препинания влияет не семантика (человека можно заменить студентом), а **структура предложения и расстановка ударения в нем:**

Сравнить:

(1)  Рыба ищет где глУбже, а человек  ищет где лУчше.

(2) РЫба ищет,  где глУбже, а человЕк ― где лУчше.

То есть при постановке тире желательно ставить и запятую.

**Замечание**

При решении пунктуационных задач **очень важен контекст**, и в частности  в этой истории со студентом (было ли там сравнение?). Если автор вопроса изначально имел в виду приведенную пословицу, то надо было на нее сослаться. Поэтому остается догадываться, почему это не было сделано.

Comment: Рыба ищет где глубже - в этом предложении не ставится запятая. Разве случаи не одинаковые?

Comment: В этой фразе можно представить ЕЙ?

Comment: Рыба ищет где глубже (= глубокие места). Это цельное по смыслу выражение.

Comment: Но и со студентом не все так ясно. "Рыба ищет где глубже, а человек где лучше" (А. Н. Островский. Доходное место)

Comment: С рыбой недосчитавшуюся запятую можно списать на "фразеологизм", но должна быть разница между _студент ищет, где лучше_ и _пьяный ищет где светлее_ (искать).

Comment: А почему должна быть разница? И структура, и семантика вроде бы совпадают.

Comment: Внимательно почитала все мнения. Запятую в заголовке оставила, так как это все-таки не фразеологизм. Вопрос оказался непростым. Всем большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Запятая, вольно или нет, раделяет заголовок на два почти независимых утверждения.
"Студент ищет" (кстати здесь пока неизвестно что/чего/кого он ищет) и "где лучше" (там где нас нет?).
Примерно как "Собака лает, караван идёт".
Без запятой этого разделения нет и фраза однознано ставит ударение на лучше а не на студента.